# Display value using HTML

Tags: html

```
file:///C:/Users/JohnReyBaylen/Desktop/sample2.html?username=asd&password=asd
```

is it possible to display the value of username and password using HTML only?

I used `form` in `HTML` and have a `method="get"`. is it possible without using `PHP` or `Javascript`, just `HTML` only?

just to know only if it is possible. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. HTML is not a programming language.

Comment: Thank you, i asked here because i don't know how to do it. One of our stupid professor give an assignment that we need to display that value without using PHP or Javascript, I know how to send using form but i dont know if it is possible to display a variable using HTML, Thank you again for your answer.